# How to send values from 1 service to another in SECA in Apache OfBiz?

Tags: ofbiz

I wanted to send partyId field value to another service to get the email-id and in turn send an email via another service.

Comment: What have you tried? Any research on your part?

Answer (score 1):

In the origin service (ex: ogriginalService, you need return an attribute:

```
<attribute name="partyId" type="String" mode="OUT" optional="false"/>
```

And in secas.xml you can invoke service:

```
 <eca service="ogriginalService" event="commit">
    <condition operator="is-not-empty" field-name="partyId"/>
    <action mode="sync" service="sendEmailService"/>
 </eca>
```